# greenDAO: ftl-templates not found

Tags: android, greendao, greendao-generator

I'm using the greenDAO for Android and I want to edit the greenDAO generator, because it overwrites @SerializedName which I need for GSON every time I change something on my database.

So I was adding greenDAO from https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO to my Android Studio project by File -> New -> Import Module... and just selected the GreenDaoGenerator-module.

Next, I build my java module to generate the greenDAO database, which uses the GreenDaoGenerator-module as dependency and I get an exception that the template dao.ftl was not found.

Can someone please help me? I'm new to Android and do not check, why it doesn't find the file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "dao.ftl" not found.
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:742)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:665)
at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.<init>(DaoGenerator.java:65)
at com.example.GreenDaoCreater.main(GreenDaoCreater.java:39)
```

Edit:
Here is a screenshot from the project structure. I hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is change in path of the template files. While I am not sure how to set the path to something relative, here is a hack that works. Open DaoGenerator.java. In the constructor, replace

```
config.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");
```

with

```
config.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("<your absolute path to templates>"));
```

You will need to find where the actual templates are stored. For me they were in `/DaoGenerator/src-template/` directory.

[image]

Comment: Absolute path is needed: Like the exact path to the src-template (Added snapshot).
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I recently re-added GreenDAO to a project of mine and when I attempted to build it I got this error.

```
TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "dao.ftl".
```

My code and template directories were unchanged from the last time I ran GreenDAO.

Simply restarting Android Studio resolved the error for me. I haven't yet investigated to discover why this is the case.